# RegExp Quantifier to Match Pattern Exactly n or m Times Instead of n to m Times

Tags: regex

I want to match 2 and 4 digit numbers. This RegExp is a obvious choice:

```
 /[0-9]{2,4}/
```

However, this matches 3 Digit numbers. Is there a way around this in regexp?

Comment: `/\d{2}|\d{4}/`

Comment: Yes, this is the solution for my Problem. How ever I hoped for a genereal solution. a Shorthand for / _P_ {n}| _P_ {m}/, as this can get out of hand for longer _P_ s.

Comment: Please provide sample strings that should match and others that shouldn't. It makes the question easy to understand.

Comment: I looking for a general solution. Finding general examples is quite hard. I hoped there was a regexp syntax like /\d{2|4}/ or the like for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use negative lookbehind/lookahead to accomplish this:

Here's one possible way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
/(?<!\d)(\d{2}|\d{4})(?!\d)/
```

This says - find a 2 or 4 digit number that is not preceded or followed by another number.  This differs from the answer above in that it will match ALL 2 and 4 digit numbers including those that are not surrounded by spaces such as the "12" in the string "abc12def".

Which way you choose will depend on what in particular you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `([0-9]{2}){1,2}`:

```
/\b([0-9]{2}){1,2}\b/
```

Above regular expression is not general; it was possible because 4 = 2 * 2.

More general solution is:

```
/\b[0-9]{2}\b|\b[0-9]{4}\b/
```

NOTE: `\b` (word boundary) was used to prevent matching 2 digits from 3 digits (or 5, 6, ... digit string).

Comment: Typo in the second regex `{` should be `[` Why not use `\d`? And isn't the first solution sufficient?

Comment: @MYGz, Thank you. I fixed it according to your comment.